# Perturbations to a vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

I ran into some problems while working through a proof of the Poincare-Hopf theorem that essentially boiled down to the following question: given a smooth vector field $V$ on a (compact Riemannian) smooth manifold $M$ with a non-degenerate zero $p\in M$, is it possible to find coordinates $y$ around a small neighbourhood of $p$ such that, on $U$, the coordinates of $V$ are given by $Ay$ for some constant matrix $A$?

I cannot prove that this can be done, but neither can I think of a counter-example to show it definitely cannot be done. My question is two-fold, with the second part being more urgent.

1) What, if any, is a counter-example to such a construction being possible?

2) Is it always possible to perturb $V$ slightly so that each of the zeros of perturbed vector field is hyperbolic (in which case the Hartman-Grobman theorem could help), but without changing the sign of the index of the zero?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128980/linearization-of-vector-fields is relevant and its answers answer yours (at least 1). Bottomline is: you cannot always smoothly linearize a vector near a zero. If you allow perturbations (which might be what you are after, I am not sure I understand what you mean overall) then you might be able to get much using the Poincaré linearization theorem (it is sufficient to get rid of reasonant eigenvalues, which are generically absent). A quick and dirty search lead me to http://cmup.fc.up.pt/cmup/preprints/2004-05.pdf where you should get refs.